# package-install wrong-type-argument error

Tags: emacs, emacs23

When I do `M-x package-install <ret> dsvn <ret>`, I get a wrong-type-argument error. This started with a recent Emacs package update. I can't figure it out.

[=========]

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
string-match("\\`https?:" nil)
package-download-single(dsvn "20130120.1457" "Subversion interface [svn]" nil)
package-download-transaction((dsvn))
package-install(dsvn)
ad-Orig-call-interactively(package-install record nil)
call-interactively(package-install record nil)
command-execute(package-install record)
smex-read-and-run(("package-install" "package-list-packages" "fringe-mode" "eval-buffer" "ansi-term" "scroll-bar-mode" "list-faces-display" "customize-variable" "delete-trailing-whitespace" "compile" "comint-run" "emacs-lisp-mode" "comint-mode" "toggle-read-only" "message-mode" "end-of-buffer" "helm-end-of-buffer" "cua-paste" "cua-cut-region" "elscreen-toggle" "ergoemacs-mode" "previous-buffer" "doremi-buffers+" "delete-file" "show-smartparens-mode" "show-paren-mode" "server-start" "python-mode" "projectile-mode" "indent-region" "eval-expression" "key-combo-mode" "emacs-init-time" "byte-recompile-directory" "doremi-all-faces-fg+" "irc" "golden-ratio-mode" "menu-bar-select-buffer" "menu-bar-open" "doremi-global-marks+" "doremi-window-width+" "beginning-of-buffer" "finder-by-keyword" "subword-mode" "fastnav-jump-to-char-forward" "fastnav-sprint-forward" "describe-bindings" "helm-find-files" "helm-for-files" "helm-ack" ...))
ad-Orig-smex()
smex()
(lambda nil (interactive) (or (boundp (quote smex-cache)) (smex-initialize)) (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") (quote smex)) (smex))()
ad-Orig-call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (or (boundp (quote smex-cache)) (smex-initialize)) (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") (quote smex)) (smex)) nil nil)
call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (or (boundp (quote smex-cache)) (smex-initialize)) (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") (quote smex)) (smex)) nil nil)
```

EDIT: I have not changed anything, and now packages aren't even listed.

Comment: See https://github.com/cask/epl/issues/7.  Is this the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your Emacs `init`:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

Or <kbd>C-:</kbd> *enter the the above snippet*.

Then <kbd>M-x</kbd>`package-refresh-contents`

And try doing what you have stated above.

Easier way seems to be: <kbd>M-x</kbd>`list-packages`.

Comment: This does not fix the problem. For some reason, even though `package-archives` is set in my `init`, it's `nil` when I eval it in the list-packages buffer. Setting it does not help. :(

Comment: Alright, doing a second package-list-packages after I set the variable solves the problem. I can make this permanent by moving the declaration to the bottom of my init.

Comment: Make sure the URL ends with a forward-slash.  When downloading package contents emacs just appends to the URL without checking whether the user included that slash, resulting in an error.